# Make a domain point to another domain

Tags: domains, htaccess

I have never been able to figure out how to do this.

I am working on a PHP script. With my script, each user will have access to their own site.

For example, the URL for this would be `myscript.com/frontend/username` where this uses an htaccess file to generate their site based on the username in the URL. (hope this makes sense).

Now I want to make it so that they can have their domain point to this.

For example, lets say their domain name is `theirsite.com`.

I want to make it so that, say if someone visits `theirsite.com/about` it really points to `myscript.com/frontend/username/about`

More examples:

- `theirsite.com/about` should point to `myscript.com/frontend/username/about`
- `theirsite.com/blog/post-12` should point to `myscript.com/frontend/username/blog/post-12`
- `theirsite.com` should point to `myscript.com/frontend/username`

How do I do this?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. I just don't understand why. Why are you recreating the wheel? What is wrong with multi-hosting the way it was designed to work? If you need a control panel, that is easy to take care of. What am I missing? What problem are you trying to resolve that I am not seeing? That may help us to address your question.

Comment: @closetnoc: What do you mean by "multi-hosting"?

Comment: Hosting more than one site on a server. Hence the multi. ;-) The reason why I asked the question was because the goal was not exactly clear. It seems like existing product will do the same thing. In fact, it seems your answer addresses my point.

Comment: the reason for this is so that my users can instantly have access to their website with no additional setup fees or waiting required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up `theirsite.com` as a [parked domain](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ParkedDomains) on top of `myscript.com`. This initially allows `theirsite.com` to be an *alias* for `myscript.com`. You can then use mod_rewrite (in .htaccess) to internally rewrite to the real URL (similar to what you have done already). You can only rewrite to a URL on `theirsite.com` (not `myscript.com`), which shouldn't be a problem since one is an *alias* for the other - unless there is something in your script that relies on the domain being `myscript.com`?

So, something like the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =theirsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/username/$1 [L]
```

Although you would probably skip this step and rewrite to the actual URL - which you are already doing. So this effectively replaces your current rewrite rule.

Comment: fantastic answer. exactly what i was looking for.